# how to import the existing test cases from excel file to kiwi test case Management Tool

Tags: python, kiwi

I have installed the kiwi tool according to the documentation provided. But i have around 10k test cases to be uploaded to the tool. So i want to upload the test case to the tool by using API.Is there any way to get this task to be done???

Question:-
Import test cases from excel to kiwi tool using python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.